# How to access the query fields in this LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following function in my code and I need to access the "Source_Type_Id" and "Source_Type_Name". I don't have the option to create a class to hold these values.

```
public IList getalltblsource_type(string Source_Type_Name = "")
{
    var query=db.tblsource_type
                .Where(c => c.Source_Type_Name.Contains(Source_Type_Name))
                .Select(c => new { c.Source_Type_Id, c.Source_Type_Name })
                .OrderBy(c => c.Source_Type_Name)
                .ToList();
    return query;
}
```

I need to get `query.Source_Type_Id` and `query.Source_Type_Name`

Comment: Can you use dynamic typing? (Note that the anonymous type will be internal, so you'd have problems using it from another assembly, unless you have InternalsVisibleTo.) *Why* do you not have the option of creating a class?

Comment: Reflection, `dynamic`, `Tuple<>`? Too little context.

Comment: do you need take the first item query.Source_Type_Id and query.Source_Type_Name? What item do you need to take?

Comment: @JonSkeet, dynamic worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, by the way...

Comment: @Dennis, Thank you for your reply. I apologize I'm not sure what else I should have provided

Comment: @StepUp, I would loop on query and access every item

Comment: @JonSkeet, I inherited the code. I agree with you.

Comment: You are returning a list sot make sure you include the index (or enumerate through the list). The code should be : .Select(c => new { type = c.Source_Type_Id, name = c.Source_Type_Name })

Answer (score 0):

From Jon Skeet and Dennis answers in comments. I used dynamic typing. Here's an example:

```
 dynamic query=db.tblsource_type.Where(c => c.Source_Type_Name.Contains(Source_Type_Name)).Select(c => new { c.Source_Type_Id, c.Source_Type_Name }).OrderBy(c => c.Source_Type_Name).ToList();
 int s = query.Source_Type_Id;
```